# Opening an app in GooglePlayStore from cocos2d js application

Tags: google-play, cocos2d-js

In my cocos2d js application i want to open the app present in play store so that user can provide a rating to it when he clicks a rate button.

There are sample codes present using cocos2d-x but no code for cocos2d js???...

It would be helpful if anyone can tell how to do this...

Thanks.